# How to get tag value for an imageview in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, imageview

Hi i have an ipad app in that i have so many small images on view. each imageview having tag value. now my job is when ever the user touch any imageview which are avaialble on view we have to fetch that particular imageview tag value in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Add a TapGesture for image. Then you can log it to see what is the tag of the image.To be able fetch that particular imageview tag value.
Like this:

```
NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        imageView.tag = i;

        NSLog(@"%d", imageView.tag);

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTag:)];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

- (void)imageTag:(id)sender {
    switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag)      
{
    case 0:
    ...
    case 1:
    ...
  }
}
```